# Refactoring a bad 'code smell' in multiplication of columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've another question about efficiency. 
I have the following kind of multiplication:

```
df['Allocated'] = df['Base Days'] * df['Base (MW) Allocated'] * 24
df['Bought'] = df['Base Days'] * df['Base (MW) Bought'] * 24
df['Sold'] = df['Base Days'] * df['Base (MW) Bought'] * 24
df['Remaining'] = df['Base Days'] * df['Base (MW) Remaining'] * 24
```

I was thinking of using a for loop - but does anyone have a more efficient way in terms of typing. Or is something like this the most efficient way. 
I could define a function

```
  def multiply(df['X']): 
      return df['X'] * df['Base Days'] * 24
```

That might make the code more reusable. Does anyone have any other ideas,
it just feels like I am doing a bad code smell - and I'd like some advice on how I could improve it.

Comment: Your `def multiply` is wrong, it won't work. def multiply(df['X']):                    ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: This may be more appropriate for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Ok I wrote the def multiple of the top of my head - I'll check and edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no inherent 'bad code smell' about this sort of thing. For example, suppose that in the future one of the columns, say `'Base (MW) Bought'` will need to be treated differently than the others. In that case, it would actually be a virtue that each different multiplication step was handled explicitly, rather than implicitly inside a function call or as an iteration of a loop.

However, I can appreciate the fact that it seems like there are wasted characters, since you're repeating the logic of `*24` and the access to `'Base Days'`.

What I might do is create some options for future extension or ways to add flexibility later, but still more or less use your `multiply` idea:

```
def baseMultiply(data, colToMul, baseCol='Base Days', convFactor=24, preTreat=None):
    col_data = data[colToMult]
    if preTreat is not None:
        col_data = preTreat(col_data)
    return data[baseCol] * col_data * convFactor
```

Then perform the multiplication and assignment in a loop:

```
col_prefix = "Base (MW) "
for col in ['Allocated', 'Bought', 'Sold', 'Remaining']:
    df[col] = baseMultiply(df, col_prefix + col)
```

Then say later you want to remove outliers but only in the case when you report the number for `'Bought'` (that's unrealistic, but it's just an example). You could write a helper function like:

```
def removeOutlier(lowerBound, upperBound, colData):
    return colData.clip(lowerBound, upperBound)
```

And we can use `functools.partial` to bind some arguments to this guy.

```
import functools
boughtColClipper = functools.partial(removeOutlier, 5, 105)
```

Now we can modify the loop above to check when we are at the `'Bought'` column, and to give this function as the keyword argument `preTreat` in that case:

```
col_prefix = "Base (MW) "
for col in ['Allocated', 'Bought', 'Sold', 'Remaining']:
    treatment = None if col != 'Bought' else boughtColClipper
    df[col] = baseMultiply(df, col_prefix + col, preTreat=treatment)
```

Now it's at least somewhat more extensible to permit later data cleaning, outlier clipping, winsorization, variable z-scoring or whatever, which are the usual things that come up later and require painfully going back and breaking earlier code.

A final trick that I often use is a name-mapping. Instead of iterating over a `list` of the column names like I have done above (which implicitly assumes that the assignment names will be the same or derived directly from the existing names), you can give a dict mapping.

For example, in the original post, you were assigning into the new name "Sold" but on the right-hand-side it was calculated from "Base (MW) Bought" and **not** from "Base (MW) Sold". I assumed this was a typo and so I used "Base (MW) Sold" in my code.

But let's suppose it was not a typo and that two different "output names" (both "Bought" and "Sold") come from one input name ("Base (MW) Bought").

```
namesToAssign = {"Allocated":"Allocated", 
                 "Bought":"Bought", 
                 "Sold":"Bought", 
                 "Remaining":"Remaining"}

col_prefix = "Base (MW) "
for newCol, oldCol in namesToAssign.iteritems():
    treatment = None if newCol != 'Bought' else boughtColClipper
    df[newCol] = baseMultiply(df, col_prefix + oldCol, preTreat=treatment)
```

You can even go one step further and have a mapping from the existing columns to *both* the new output column and also the pre-treatment functions, such as:

```
namesAndTreatments = {"Allocated":("Allocated", None), 
                      "Bought":("Bought", boughtColClipper),
                      "Sold":("Bought", None), 
                      "Remaining":("Remaining", None)}

col_prefix = "Base (MW) "
for newCol, (oldCol, treatment) in namesToAssign.iteritems():
    df[newCol] = baseMultiply(df, col_prefix + oldCol, preTreat=treatment)
```

and even this could be further extended so that the values inside of `namesAndTreatments` each contain extra arguments, logging handlers, database connections for fallback data if the data is bad, etc., etc. At that point, you'd want to refactor whatever `namesAndTreatments` is to be its own class of some sort, and to make functions like `baseMultiply` work by unpackaging the member data attributes of that class (it will help with compartmentalization and testing, whereas a `dict` that just grows and grows in its responsibility will be hard to maintain).

Comment: That was more than I expected - really interesting hearing about how you could use functools here :) Thanks. In this case the conversion is constant but I appreciate your point about it not necessarily being a bad code smell - since in theory the conversion could change